# Force an update to git log

Tags: git

I am very new to git.  Don't know what happened, but somehow some update comments I made to a file were lost, i.e. they don't show up in the git log.  Somehow, though, it looks like the actual updated file has indeed been saved by git.  How do I correct this in the log?  Is there maybe just a way to do a forced checkin?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail? What does git log show, and what do you expect it to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a commit statement by using

```
git commit --amend -m "commit message"
```